# Create Facebook Page - facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that uses Facebook login module.

I tried to get `manage_page` and `publish_page` permissions but Facebook is not giving these permission without review. So, I tried to create test user and gave him above permissions.

Then logged into Facebook with test user. Facebook is not letting test user to create facebook page.

I need to access user's pages but cannot do because I cannot create at the first place.

Comment: why not just go through review?

Comment: Test users can not interact with “real” pages; you would have to login to Facebook _as_ the test user, and then let them create a page via the UI. Easier to test, if you don’t use a test user, but add a real user account to the admin/dev roles.